# Add CALayer to fill entire UIView Content

Tags: xamarin.ios

I want to add a CALayer to a UIView but the content of the CALayer must fill the entire width/height of the UIView.

Please advise.

Comment: CALayer layer = new CALayer(); layer.Frame = View.Bounds; View.Layer.AddSublayer(layer);

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
CALayer myLayer = new CALayer();
myLayer.Bounds = new CGRect(0, 0,View.Bounds.Width,View.Bounds.Height);
```

That's it